# session error in php forms

Tags: php, html

This is my code:-

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<h2>working time</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<button name="starttime" class="starttime">starttime</button>
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
if(isset($_POST["starttime"])){
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$date1 = date('H:i:s');
require "database.php";
$n = "";
$d = "";
$sql = "SELECT name, ddate FROM karthick.date WHERE name = '$name' AND ddate = '$date'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $n = $row["name"];
        $d = $row["ddate"];
    }
}
if($n == $name && $d == $date){
    echo'<script>
    alert("Time already registered");
    </script>';
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO karthick.date (name, ddate, starttime) VALUES ('$name', '$date', '$date1')";
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "starttime inserted";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
}
}
?>
</form>
<form action = "" method="post">
<button name="endtime" class="endtime">Endtime</button>
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
if(isset($_POST["endtime"])){
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$date1 = date('H:i:s');
require "database.php";
$n = "";
$d = "";
$sql = "SELECT name, ddate, endtime FROM karthick.date WHERE name = '$name' AND ddate = '$date'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $e = $row["endtime"];
    }
}
if($e != '00:00:00'){
    echo'<script>
    alert("Time already registered");
    </script>';
}else{
    $sql = "UPDATE karthick.date SET endtime='$date1' WHERE name = '$name' AND ddate = '$date'";
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "Endtime inserted.<br>";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
    $sql1 = "UPDATE karthick.date SET worked = (endtime - starttime) WHERE name = '$name' AND ddate = '$date'";
    if($conn->query($sql1) == TRUE){
        echo "worked time updated";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
}
}
?>
</form>
<form action="user.php" method="post">
<button name= "logout" class="logout">Logout</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As I run this code it shows me an interrupting message.

> Notice:A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

But the code works fine. Is there any way to hide the notice message?

[image]

Comment: Notice clearly says that you are starting your session twice

Comment: remove `session_start();` inside the form

Comment: You are some how including `"uatten.php"` (Probably through `database.php`) you should make sure you are only starting the session once in all your includes =]

Comment: You only need to call `session_start()` ONCE per script. It should ALSO be called before you output anything to the browser. So you are either calling it again before the script you show us is run, OR you are also getting another session error like **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent** _Have a look at your PHP Error log_

Comment: the error gone after i removed one of the session_start()

Comment: @pkarthicbz  thanks for marking. Please up-vote too. up-vote others also if they are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one time `session_start()` is needed on a page (on top). You have it two times in your page so remove the second one.

Suggestion:-

Always use some error reporting code.

example:-

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of errors
ini_set('display_errors',1);// display those errors
```

Always add this to your `php` script in the beginning. It will help you a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @Pepo_rasta always. BTW  you can check my other all answers. most of the time i used that error reporting code. Meanwhile i am not the down-voter.

Answer (score 1):

remove `session_start()` from your file.
Because u started session twice.
Either the file u r included in your code in that u started session.
so please go through u r code once again

Answer (score 0):

use `session_start();` only once and before sending any output (at the very start of page)

or turn of error reporting(not recommended):

- add `error_reporting(0);` at the beggining of page to hide all errors
  and notices
- add `@` character before command that causing error or notice( eg.
  `@session_start();`)

Comment: "what i want is to get rid of the error is there any way to hide the error from showing?" downvoted anyway....

Comment: never ever suggest to skip from errors while programing. you did just opposite. I am afraid you will get more -ve marks.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<h2>working time</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<button name="starttime" class="starttime">starttime</button>
<?php
session_start();
```

to

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
<center>
<h2>working time</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<button name="starttime" class="starttime">starttime</button>
<?php
```